# how to change field type and retain choices defined in model django 3.0

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django, I am trying to change field type by retaining choices defined in model.

this is my model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Type(models.IntegerChoices):
        INDIRECT= 0
        DIRECT = 1
        BOTH = 2

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=Type.choices)
    price= models.IntegerField()
```

and this is my form class

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = SPA
        fields = [ 'name', 'category', 'price' ]
```

I know we can change the field type with the above commented line. but it doesn't bring choices from model....

Please advice how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to alther the widget, you better specify that in the `Meta` class by passing a dictionary to the [**`widgets`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets):

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SPA
        fields = [ 'name', 'category', 'price' ]
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.RadioSelect
        }
```

This thus leaves the construction of the model form intact, and thus will specify choices from the model, etc. Yes you can manually specify the choices, but if you later would for example alter the field, then you have to alter the form field as well. By specifying the widget, you let Django automate the rest.

If you still want to define the form fied, you can obtain the choices from the model:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SPA.category.choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = SPA
        fields = [ 'name', 'category', 'price' ]
```